# Image Continuously Refreshing (Blink) Issue When Changing Data with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm Designing an Online Game. There are Items in the game. While updating the Percentage value of the items, the pictures are constantly refreshed and in this case, blinking (blinking problem) occurs. How can i solve this problem.

Can I do this in a different way by changing my HTML and CSS code?

**Problem:**

[image]

```js
var percent = 0;

var countdown = setInterval(function () {
 percent++;
 $(".food_container > div").each(function(index, element) {  
    if(percent == 100){ clearInterval(countdown) }
    $(element).css({"--value": percent + "%"}).attr("data-value",percent + "%");
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
body{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35C10D, #6FE814);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   
}
.food_container{
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}
.food_container > div {
    background-image: var(--image-url);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.food_container > div:before {
    content: attr(data-value);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 9pt;
    align-items: end;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    right: 0;
    height: calc(var(--value) + 20px);
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 -7px 22px -7px rgb(255 255 255 / 12%), 0 -7px 5px -7px white;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 58%);
    background-image: var(--image-url);
    background-size: 60px;
    background-position: center bottom 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: grayscale(1) brightness(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="food_container">

<div style="--value: 0%;--image-url: url(https://svgur.com/i/hrP.svg);" data-value="0%"></div>
<div style="--value: 0%;--image-url: url(https://svgur.com/i/hrm.svg);" data-value="0%"></div>
<div style="--value: 0%;--image-url: url(https://svgur.com/i/hrQ.svg);" data-value="0%"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any browser extensions to clear cache?

Comment: @lance The problem happens when F12 (Console) is open. I guess normally there is no problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @lance I tried to solve the problem using IMG tags.

Comment: What if you would set background image in your script even if you already set it up in css

Comment: @lance  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245174/discussion-between-lance-and-morgan-codes).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no problem with my codes. The problem was related to the console ( F12 ) being open. I noticed this.